# При попытке создать проект в Android Studio получаю ошибки

Tags: android, android-studio

При попытке создать проект в Android Studio получаю такие ошибки.

[image: скриншот ошибок]

Система Windows 7x64.
Собственно вопрос, куда копать и в каком направлении. Заранее спасибо!

UPDATE - gradle файл
build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

и еще один:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ivybank.plesser_os.headfirstandroid"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Покажите gradle файлы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вопрос

Comment: А вы уверены что вам нужны все эти штуки для тестов?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб честно говоря не знаю, так как студия сама это туда вставляет (дома под линуксом таких проблем нет, на работе вот поставил и вот столкнулся)

Comment: Ну, если не знаете значит и не нужно) Просто удалить зависимости с тестами - `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` и `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})` и `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо!

Comment: А другие зависимости тянутся нормально, например ретрофит?

Comment: @temq не грузится :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Студия (точнее gradle) не может по какой-то причине подключить зависимости. В данном случае - либы для автоматизированного тестирования. Они по умолчанию включены в дефолтный проект студии.

Если эти тесты вам не нужны, то вы можете просто их удалить - `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` и `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espres‌​so-core:2.2.2', { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' })` и `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

Answer (score 0):

Раз из дома все грузится нормально, а на работе нет, то скорей всего на работе интернет идет через прокси. Для корректной работы узнайте настройки для прокси, потом создайте файл `gradle.properties` в глобальной папке gradle(как правило она находится в папке пользователя и называется `.gradle` и добавте в него настройки примерно так:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=порт
systemProp.https.proxyHost=хост
```

После этого для всех проектов на данной машине не явно будут применяться эти настройки.

Comment: Это уже все сделано. Он перед этим ругался, но мы смотрели на логи прокси и андроид студии  и давали разрешения на требуемые адреса. Последний лог который мы сняли (прежде чем я написал сюда) был без ошибок о connection failed

Comment: Кстати для ретрофита я открыл проксюи он встал.